# Reset Exposed filter on change in Drupal 7 Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have 2 exposed filters in a view. I need just one filter to work at a time.
So if I choose one filter at previous query it should be reseted when i choose another filter.

Filter by Category. Filter by Capacity.
Category OR Capacity.

If i use operator OR Instead of AND it doesnt help. It doesn't filter right.
It shows content in strange order.

Answer (score 2):

Advanced >> Exposed form style >> settings >>

There is a check box for reset button. Check that and you should be done.

Comment: yep - always love the simple, 'use as designed' answers, and I always forget where to find this setting. Useful answer! for anyone who loves the history of changes, here's the link to 'how we got this feature' (what a nerd I can be :) ) https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/99370

Answer (score 1):

On the views exposed filter settings, **uncheck** the this option

**"Remember the last selection"**

[image]

Or,

You can try [View hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module.

I found this on Project page:

> ```
> Views Filters Reset
> ```
>
> Reset is initially off for all views. To turn it on, go to the
>   Administer > Site configuration > Views Filters Reset page
>   (admin/settings/views_filters_reset) and select the views where the
>   reset button should be active.
>
> Reset button supports Ajax-enabled views as well.

Comment: Thank you. I know that thing.
But it remembers the whole exposed filter when you got back next time.

What i want is reset the filters each time you make choice.

Comment: you can use "Better exposed filter", using this you can put the "Reset button" on the filters. https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters